# Parse json in Asynctask, No result expected

Tags: java, json, parsing, android-asynctask

I'm trying to parse JSON in AsyncTask and so far everything works fine but does not show me the result I hope.

PHP CODE:

```
  if($row>0){
$resultado["productos"][]=array("logstatus"=>$nombre);
 }
 else{
$resultado["productos"][]=array("logstatus"=>"0");
}
echo json_encode( $resultado );
```

RESULT:

```
{"productos":[{"logstatus":"nombre"}]}
```

JAVA CODE:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                            .getJSONfromURL("url/file.php");

                    if(jsonobject != null){         
                    try {
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("productos");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects
                            map.put("logstatus", jsonobject.getString("logstatus"));
                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());         
                    }
                    }else{
                        //Log.e("Response","No data");
                    }
                    return null;
                }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
        for (Symbol sym : syms) {
            if("".equals(sym.getData())){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                finish();
                barcodeScanned = true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Not found"+arraylist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();          
    }
```

When you run the AsyncTask shows a Toast with the message: Not found = [{"logstatus": "name"}] and I need to remove [{}] and only get the value "name".

How I can get that result? Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have one object in arraylist you could use that code:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Not found" + arraylist.get(0).get("logstatus"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```